# htmx and django Class Based Views

Tags: django, htmx

I was trying to convert the countdown tutorial from [here](https://htmx-django.com/blog/how-to-implement-countdown-timer-in-django-via-htm) to Class-Based Views but I do not know what is missing.

views.py

```
class TimeDifferenceView(TemplateView):
    
    delta = datetime(2022, 12, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) - timezone.now()
    template_name = 'base.html'
    days = delta.days
    seconds = delta.seconds % 60
    minutes = (delta.seconds //60) % 60
    hours = delta.seconds // 3600
    
    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get the context
        context = super(TimeDifferenceView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # Create any data and add it to the context.
        context['days'] = self.days
        context['seconds'] = self.seconds
        context['minutes'] = self.minutes
        context['hours'] = self.hours
        return context
```

base.html

```
<div
id= "time" 
class="d-flex justify-content-between"
hx-get="{% url 'time_difference' %}"
hx-trigger="every 1s"
hx-select="#time" 
hx-swap="outerHTML"
>    
            <div>
              <h5>Days</h5>
              <p> {{days}} </p>
            </div>
       
            <div>
              <h5>Hours</h5>
              <p> {{hours}} </p>
            </div>
          
            <div>
              <h5>Minutes</h5>
              <p> {{minutes}} </p>
            </div>
        
            <div>
              <h5>Seconds</h5>
              <p> {{seconds}} </p>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @chuysc_ this is the working code.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render


class TimeDifferenceView(View):
    
    template_name = 'base.html'
    
    def get(self, request):
        
        delta = datetime(2022, 12, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) - timezone.now()

        context = {
            'days': delta.days,
            'seconds': delta.seconds % 60,
            'minutes': (delta.seconds //60) % 60,
            'hours': delta.seconds // 3600
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```